# returning clicked li class in an ul javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, listitem

My code (the html page):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="homeLink"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="rekenLink"><a href="#">Rekenmachine</a></li>
        <li id="bakkerLink"><a href="#">Parkeergarage</a></li>
        <li id="garageLink"><a href="#">Bij de bakker</a></li>
    <ul>
</nav>
```

The javascript/jquery behind it:

```
$(function () {
    $("ul").click(function () {
        // here I want to get the clicked id of the li (e.g. bakkerLink)
    });
});
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I am pretty sure this has been asked and answered hundreds of times, you should try and search previously asked questions (or look at some simple jQuery examples) before posting a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with signature `$(common_parent).on(event_name, filter_selector, event_listener)`.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gLhbA/

```
$(function() {
    $("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
        // here I want to get the clicked id of the li (e.g. bakkerLink)
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Another method is to bind the event to `li` instead of `ul`:

```
$(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
        // here I want to get the clicked id of the li (e.g. bakkerLink)
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Little bit too late, but the same answer as the top answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Ridz Are you aware that Rob W's answer was the first one? Look at the time above his name.

Comment: @Ridz: the first answered get pushed to the bottom as new answers get added

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I don't aks questions on here very often so I did not know that. Thanks :p

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

edit: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/j5gky/)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this answer. Why was this downvoted. This is much straightforward right?

Comment: how does this not answer your question?

Comment: You use "li" while I clearly state using "ul" because it refers to all of them.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. i have moved the other half into a comment. thank you

Comment: @Ridz i was not trying to offend, is there a specific reason you cannot attach the handler to "li"?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `on()` instead of `click` and pass `li` as selector.

```
$(function() {
    $("ul").on('click', 'li', function() {
        //Here this will point to the li element being clicked
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

`on()` reference - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Best answer. At least you read I was $("ul") instead of li. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `click` event of the `<li>` instead of the `<ul>`.
You can then get `this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event's target (The anchor that was clicked) and then grab its parent's id:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul").click(function(e) {
        alert(e.target.parentNode.id);
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9JfG2/)

Answer (score 0):

here is one of the way to do. Make sure your using the latest jquery file.

```
 $("ul li").on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
$(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: The question is about getting the id of 'li'. not 'ul'