# Adding select feature for JQuery mobile Autocomplete field

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need an autocomplete input text field in my jquery mobile application, so i am using this below code

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html

This code is showing how to display suggestions, what i need to add to this code so that i can select a field from the listed suggestions and once i select one that will get populated to the input field

Comment: to the same input field or another one?

Comment: this component available in 1.4.2 could be what you want : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom-filter/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some kind of OnClick-event to the list-items.

In the source code provided by that page, you can see that the list items are simply displayed as list-items.

```
$.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
});
```

So what you can do is either add a `.click()` listener to the `ul`-element, or to the `li`-elements.

An example could be like this ([jsFiddle example of how click-events could work](http://jsfiddle.net/ybFCx/)):

```
 $('li').click(function () {
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Then you'll simply have to catch the text and replace the typed text with the text retrieved from the dropdown list.

Edit: Have you tried this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726264/1513735

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hekja, i used similar kind of code i am able to catch an event on ul, but i am not able to on 'li' elements reason might be they formed on the fly. any suggestion on this?