# how to set "this" as the child element in onclick event

Tags: javascript, onclick, this

**EDIT 2**:

Actually, What I was trying to do is passing img properties to server-side, because google app script is javascript in server side. And passing data to server can only be as string. The solution I found is adding a usual img property with value an object containing everything I want (id, src, ... of my img. I JSON.stringified this value and BOOM ... Now I get every data I need.
Thank you for your help and sorry for the misunderstood.

**EDIT**:

Thanks to this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726264/1859295

I could finally find a solution to my question.

I used an .on() method on my ul list and now my "this" is pointing to my img element.

**Original Post:**

I have an empty ul. 
I append li with js.
li's contain img with src, id, name attribute AND onclick event which fires a function with "this" as parameter. 
I need my "this" to be the img element within my li. Instead, I get my ul as "this"

my code is:

```
function createItemsList(items){ 
    $("#items").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      $("#items").append('<li class="w3-display-container" 
     id="test"><img src="'+ items[i].url + '" id ="'+ items[i].id + 
     '" style="height:25px;" 
     onclick="google.script.run.addItem(this)"; return false; 
     class="w3-ripple"></li>');
          }
        };


        google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(createItemsList)
              .getItemsList();
```

Comment: use `addEventListener` the call will receive `event` and `event.target` is your `element`

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways of creating elements with jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  let img = $("<img/>", {
    src: items[i].url,
    id: items[i].id,
    css: { height: "25px" },
    click: function() { google.script.run.addItem(this); },
    "class": "w3-ripple"
  });
  let li = $("<li/>", {
     "class": "w3-display-container"
     html: img
  });
  $("#items").append(li);
}
```

The `$("<tagname/>")` facility accepts a second argument with properties for the new element. You can include handler functions with that. It's much neater than trying to juggle quote characters in pieced-together HTML via strings.

Comment: This look like a perfect solution and it seems like you took the time to really read my problem. 
What I see by the way you declare your variables with "let" is that you use the ECMAScript 2015 version of JS, which is something that google app script can't handle. So I change the let 's by var 's. 
It is not working. Maybe the syntaxe you are using is still part of this ECMAScript 2015 ?

Comment: @user1859295 you can use `var`. The idea here is just basic jQuery. When you say "it is not working", what does that mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: This $("<tagname/>") facility seems to be so much nicer than what I do struggling with strings

Comment: the list won't even show up. The only way I know to "debug" is the console. It says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: I think a comma , was missing before html : img . So I deleted the part "class": "w3..." Now the list shows up but ...

Comment: Console says : " Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0 " ... Just like it said with my solution

Comment: "this" is still an array of object

Comment: Well a jQuery event handler will always be invoked with `this` a reference to the clicked element. Have you tried a `console.log("click: this is: ", this)` in the handler?

Comment: I can Logger.log in app script editor. 'This' is always an array of object, basically all my images elements... Using "this.src", in the other hand was always good pointing to clicked image.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the inside for as following

```
 var img = $('<img />').attr('src', items[i].url).attr('id', items[i].id);
    img.click(function() {
        google.script.run.addItem(this)
    })
    $("#items").append('<li class="w3-display-container" id="test">').append(img);
```

Basically to use click eventhandler from jquery so I think this will be img.